# Site secure with SSL but when refresh SSL disappears

Tags: php, .htaccess, security, ssl, https

So I have a website that uses SSL and a user picked up something I did not notice. Once the user clicks a link the site shows SSL, when the user refreshes the website the SSL disappears. But when they click any links on the website it will appear again. The SSL only disappears when someone refreshes the page.

**Website secure on all links**
[Secure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nBeT7.png)

**Website SSL does not appear after refreshing page**
[Non-Secure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OLhqR.png)

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# Redirect non www. to www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.website\.co\.uk
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.website.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]

# Redirect http to https editor nathan 18/01/2017
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# Remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Have you tried something like Firefox Developer Tools -> Network to see what is happening when the page loads/refreshes?

Comment: it could cause by many things like resource loading from http instead of https

Comment: I will try the firefox option and maybe change http to https instead. Kind regards

Comment: should this be like that RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off?

Comment: @justbaron For some reason viewing the website on FireFox after refresh the SSL doesn't disappear. On Google chrome it does. I have used Firefox developer tools -> Network and cannot see any issues. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Whitena use the GoogleChrome Developer Tools -> Network `F12` and see whats going on.

Comment: @justbaron Just performed this check also and there is no issue when I refresh. Network and Security say the website is secure. But once I come of developer tool and refresh it shows the website isnt. Im baffled.

Comment: @Whitena can you attach screenshot of console

Comment: @AbdulRafay Ok so when I refreshed it changed to non secure and I pressed F12 -> Network and it says this. Mixed Content
The site includes HTTP resources.
Reload the page to record requests for HTTP resources.

Comment: @Whitena the mixed content means one of `(js, image, and/or css)` is loaded with non https link i.e. (`http://domain/linkto.css`) check your console for the file (which file is loaded without ssl/https

Comment: @AbdulRafay found out the issue, It was a favicon.ico that had http instead of https. Thank you for your help and support. Finally resolved it.

Comment: @Whitena please check the answer so it could help others

Comment: @AbdulRafay Hi the answer you provided wasn't what I needed I have created the answer below in my comment. Kind regards

Comment: @Whitena it's same i did gave example that error happens on that, it can be any file which is linked non https/ssl not just favicon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to do a check on Google Chrome F12 -> Network and I noticed that

> Mixed Content The site includes HTTP resources. Reload the page to record requests for HTTP resources

I noticed the favicon.ico had http instead of https: now fixed

```
<link rel="icon" href="https://www.website.co.uk/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
```

Answer (score 0):

> It can be caused by content loaded without https

here's an example

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://example.com/linkto.css">
```

change it to

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://example.com/linkto.css">
```

or

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//example.com/linkto.css">
```